# Leiningen not working MacOs Mojave due to Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not locate clojure/tools/nrepl/server__init.class

Tags: clojure, leiningen

I am on Mojave and can't get leiningen to work.

I was using java 8, and then tried upgrading to 11 to no avail. Currently using:

```
openjdk version "11.0.7" 2020-04-14
OpenJDK Runtime Environment AdoptOpenJDK (buildb11.0.7+10)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM AdoptOpenJDK (build 11.0.7+10, mixed mode)
```

I have tried copying lein to my /usr/local/bin and brew install but in both cases I get the error:

```
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not locate clojure/tools/nrepl/server__init.class, clojure/tools/nrepl/server.clj or clojure/tools/nrepl/server.cljc on classpath.
```

Comment: Can you share some more information? How do you run leiningen? What is your project setup? Usually, nrepl should just come up inside a leiningen project. See https://nrepl.org/nrepl/usage/server.html#_using_leiningen

Comment: So I was merely trying to learn clojure, and this seemed like one of the first steps. I merely brew installed lein and tried copying the script from github. More specifically I was following: https://www.braveclojure.com/getting-started/

and tried running lein new app clojure-noob

Comment: Hm, that should indeed Just Work. I'm on Linux and only ever downloaded the lein bash script manually as described on https://leiningen.org/. You are certainly on the right track!

Comment: Sadly I am on no track now! Without lein working not really sure where to go from there with clojure. I saw boot exists, so i guess i could try that, but I am really confused as to why this isn't just working.

Comment: I'm really sorry that I'm not able to help you with this. I'm on Linux, so can't test this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had a similiar problem recently on macOS Mojave (10.14.6). The following command did the trick for me:

```sh
rm -rf .lein
```

However, ***before*** you run this line, please ***make sure that***...

1. ... you are in your home directory.
2. ... .lein is a directory associated with your leiningen installation and nothing else!
3. ... that you have a backup of any config files, custom packages, etc. that are associated with your leiningen installation.

Once you hit `enter` the `.lein` directory will be deleted. The directory will be rebuild when you start the repl via leinigen `lein repl`.

Comment: Thank you, strangely enough I ended up fixing yesterday myself from a github issue! I performed a similar action, but had to just remove the profile.

So  rm ~/.lein/profiles.clj

I installed clojure awhile back and I guess what was in the profile was breaking it (something about nrepl)

Comment: Good to hear. Would you mind marking my answer as a solution?

Comment: This saved me, was having an issue where the `lein classpath` command wasn't working. Thanks!